# What is the difference between sort_values and sort_index?

Tags: python, pandas

Python Pandas provides two methods for sorting DataFrame :

- [sort_values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) (or DEPRECATED [sort](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html))
- [sort_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

What are differences between these two methods ?

Comment: They are the same. ``Sort`` is an older version that accepts a slightly different calling convention. Use ``sort_index``.

Comment: Is there a way to sort first using index, and after sort using a column name ?

Comment: make the index a column, then ``sort_index(by=['index_name','column_name')``

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As the question was updated to ask for the difference between `sort_values` (as `sort` is deprecated) and `sort_index`, the answer of @mathdan is no longer reflecting the current state with the latest pandas version (>= 0.17.0).

- `sort_values` is meant to sort **by the values of columns**
- `sort_index` is meant to sort **by the index labels** (or a specific level of the index, or the column labels when `axis=1`)

Previously, `sort` (deprecated starting from pandas 0.17.0) and `sort_index` where indeed almost identical (both methods could sort by both columns and index). But this confusing situation has been solved in 0.17.0.
For an overview of the changes in the sorting API, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.17.0.html#changes-to-sorting-api

Comment: It looks like the link that works now is: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.17.0.html#changes-to-sorting-api

Answer (score 7):

The difference is entirely in the way it is called. The [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/1d94dd2ada7d0af57c245b083d26d60b8649a04e/pandas/core/frame.py#L2813) for `sort` is literally a one-line call to `sort_index`.